# Average distance from point to circle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, expectation

I need to find the average distance from the origin of the Euclidean plane to the points on a circle with radius $R$. The distance from the origin to the center of the circle is denoted by $r$. Observe that there's no requirement on $r$ and $R$, i.e., we can have $R \geq r$ (the origin is inside the circle) or $R \leq r$ (the origin is outside the circle).

Tentative solution: let $\phi$ denote a random variable uniformly distributed in $[0, 2 \pi]$. The average distance to the circle is given by

$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^{2} + R^{2} + 2 r R \cos \phi} \ \mathrm{d} \phi$

Any idea on how to solve this integral? I've tried substituting $\cos \phi \to z$ but it doesn't get any better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you integrating from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @Couchy311 Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the integration limits from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer it not what you would like to hear.

There is nothing more to do to your integral except to express it as the [Complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

Using $\cos\phi$ even and substituting $\phi=2t$ you get:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^{2} + R^{2} + 2 r R \cos \phi} \ \mathrm{d} \phi$

$=2\int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{r^{2} + R^{2} + 2 r R \cos \phi} \ \mathrm{d} \phi$

$=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{r^{2} + R^{2} + 2 r R \cos(2t)} \ \mathrm{d} t$

$=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{r^{2} + R^{2} + 2 r R (1-2\sin^2t)} \ \mathrm{d} t$

$=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{(r+R)^{2} - 4 r R \sin^2t} \ \mathrm{d} t$

$=4(r+R)\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \frac{4 r R}{(r+R)^{2}} \sin^2t} \ \mathrm{d} t$

$=4(r+R)E\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{r R}}{r+R}\right)$

So your answer is $\frac{2}{\pi}(r+R)E\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{r R}}{r+R}\right)$

Comment: Your answer seems flawless, but when I test it on Matlab with Monte Carlo simulations, it gives different results. Here's the Matlab code that should reproduce your first 3 lines and the final solution:

`R=10;
r=20;

n=rand(10^6,1);

phi_1=2*pi*n;
f_1=mean(sqrt(r^2+R^2+2*r*R*cos(phi_1)))

phi_2=pi*n;
f_2=2*mean(sqrt(r^2+R^2+2*r*R*cos(phi_2)))

phi_3=pi/2*n;
f_3=4*mean(sqrt(r^2+R^2+2*r*R*cos(2*phi_3)))

[~,E]=ellipke(2*sqrt(r*R)/(r+R));
int=2/pi*(r+R)*E`

which gives the results

`f_1=21.2770
f_2=42.5432
f_3=85.0864
int=20.3850`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Anyway, what worries me the most is that f_1=21.2770 (original integral, also computed with numeric integral) and int=20.3850 (final formula). The difference is small but still...

Comment: If you look carefully at Matlab [definition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ellipke.html) of elliptic integral of the second kind (at the bottom of the page) vs. Wikipedia [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) which I used, you will see that they define the integral $E$ in terms of $m=k^2$. So your code should read `[~,E]=ellipke(4*r*R/(r+R)^2)` which gives the result $21.2709$