# Intuition: Calculate Average Distance between Point and Circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to find a solution and explanation for the following problem:
I need to find the average distance from a point to the points on a circle with a radius $R$

- The distance from the point to the center of the circle is denoted by r
- There's no requirement on $r$ and $R$, i.e., we can have $≥$
  (the origin is inside the circle) or $≤$
  (the origin is outside the circle).

In addition, I am looking for the average squared distance.

I found this answer to the first part of my question:

[Average distance from point to circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020713/average-distance-from-point-to-circle)

However, I could use some intuition. As someone who studied economics, I know some calculus, but am out of touch with geometry. I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on the equation (assuming it's correct).

Comment: Both of these are relatively easy integrals to set up. Do you know any calculus? Please [edit] the question to tell us why you want to know.

Comment: That answer is correct. Distance is computed via the cosine rule. For the averaged square distance just leave out the square root. I don't see any space for intuition here.