# Derivation: Average distance from point to circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, expected-value

I have a question in relation to this [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020713/average-distance-from-point-to-circle):

I understand the answer and its derivation, however, I do not understand the starting point of:

$$
E(d) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^{2} + R^{2} + 2 r R \cos \phi} 
\ \mathrm{d} \phi\ .
$$

To my understanding, the formula should start with the [law of cosines](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-cosine-law.html), which states:
$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 − 2ab\cos(C)$ and (in this context) would translate into:

$$d^2 = r^{2} + R^{2} - 2 r R \cos \phi$$

putting this into an integral yields:

$$
E(d) = 
\frac{1}{2 \pi} 
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^{2} + R^{2} - 2 r R \cos \phi} 
\ \mathrm{d} \phi\ .
$$

The difference is that in one case $2 r R \cos \phi$ is added and in the other substacted.

Can you tell me where the difference comes from?

Comment: @HappyDay: I am not sure. Do you think the answer could be that: $E(d) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^{2} + R^{2} + 2 r R \cos \phi} \ \mathrm{d} \phi =  \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^{2} + R^{2} - 2 r R \cos \phi} \ \mathrm{d} \phi$ because of the symmetry of a circle?

Comment: The integrals are equal, replace $\phi$ by $\phi+\pi$, so $\cos(\phi +\pi)=-\cos \phi$, this substitution moves the period interval $[0,2\pi]$ to an other period interval, move it back to $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The difference comes whether you start with B for external closing side of triangle or B for internal closing side. But it doesn't matter when taking the average.

In one case you are measuring your d's from A to B, and from B to A in the other, for same sense of angle rotation $\phi$.

Since all distances are positive it does not matter in grouping or summing i.e., whether you are considering $d's$ from maximum $R+r$ to minimum $R-r$ or from minimum $R-r$ to maximum $R+r.$ The evaluated definite integral has the same value.